# Goto the class a method belong in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

In Visual Studio, suppose already jump to a method in a very huge C++ class in a header file, how to know which class the method belong to? Now the method is scroll up until the class shows up, but sometimes you miss the class and get into another class's body.

Comment: That's a way Visual Studio is telling you your class is too big... cannot access to VS right now, but if I'm not wrong, there is a "go to implementation" command on right click menu: the implementation will show you the class name, i.e. **`MyClass`**::`myMethod()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the top of the code panel in visual studio, it shows the details like currently which project you are accessing and at which class you are in and which method you are looking into. Refer the below image,

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can hover your cursor over the function declaration and a tooltip should show you the name of the class that this method belongs to. Alternatively there is a dropdown menu in the main toolbar that shows the name of the class:

[image]